# @OneToMany relationship with @EmbeddedId, giving uninitialized proxy passed to persist()

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, hibernate-onetomany

I have googled a lot, but I have not found any solution. Error showed in the log:

```
org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: uninitialized proxy passed to persist()
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:762)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:755)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingAction$7.cascade(CascadingAction.java:315)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:399)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:342)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:263)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:151)
```

Hibernate querys in the log:

```
(SqlStatementLogger.java:104) - insert into DEST_ALERTAS (EMAIL, ID_DESTINATARIO) values (?, ?)
(SqlStatementLogger.java:104) - update DEST_ALERTAS_SISTEMA set ACTIVO=? where ID_DESTINATARIO=? and ID_SISTEMA=?
```

I am inserting a new DEST_ALERTAS, so the first insert is ok, and **the update is wrong, it should also be a insert**.

My code:

**DEST_ALERTAS entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEST_ALERTAS")
public class DestinatariosAlertasEntidad implements Serializable {

 
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Identificador_DEST_ALERTAS_PK")
  @SequenceGenerator(name = "Identificador_DEST_ALERTAS_PK", sequenceName = "SEC_GI_DEST_ALERTAS", allocationSize = 1)
  @Column(name = "ID_DESTINATARIO", unique = true, nullable = false)
  private int idDestinatario;

  @Column(name = "EMAIL", length = 100)
  private String email;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "destinatario", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Set<DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad> destinatarioSistema = new HashSet<DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad>();
```

**DEST_ALERTAS_SISTEMA entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEST_ALERTAS_SISTEMA")
public class DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad implements Serializable {


  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  
  @EmbeddedId
  private DestinatarioSistemaKey clave;

  @MapsId("idSistema")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SISTEMA", referencedColumnName = "ID_SISTEMA", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private SistemaEntidad sistema;

  @MapsId("idDestinatario")
  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_DESTINATARIO", referencedColumnName = "ID_DESTINATARIO", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  private DestinatariosAlertasEntidad destinatario;
```

Class used to map the composite key is **DestinatarioSistemaKey**

```
@Embeddable
public class DestinatarioSistemaKey implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name = "ID_SISTEMA")
    private Integer idSistema;
    
    @Column(name = "ID_DESTINATARIO")
    private Integer idDestinatario;
```

**SISTEMAS entity class**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SISTEMAS")
public class SistemaEntidad implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @Column(name = "ID_SISTEMA", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10)
  private Integer id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sistema", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<SistemaMotivoEntidad> motivos = new HashSet<SistemaMotivoEntidad>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sistema", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<SistemaCausaEntidad> causas = new HashSet<SistemaCausaEntidad>();

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sistema", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private Set<SistemaProblemaEntidad> problemas = new HashSet<SistemaProblemaEntidad>();

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TIPO_SISTEMA")
  private TipoSistemaEntidad tipo;
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/creaDestinatariosAlertas", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String creaDestinatariosAlertas(
      @Validated @ModelAttribute("filtro") FiltroDestinatarioSistemaAlertas usuarioAlerta,
      Model model, RedirectAttributes flash, SessionStatus status, HttpServletRequest request, BindingResult result) {
    
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
      return VISTA_CREACION_DESTINATARIOS_ALERTAS;
    }
    
    DestinatariosAlertasEntidad entidad = new DestinatariosAlertasEntidad();
    try {
      entidad.setEmail(usuarioAlerta.getEmail());
      entidad.setDestinatarioSistema(obtenerListaEntidad(usuarioAlerta.getSistemas(), entidad));
      alertasServicio.guardarDestinatario(entidad);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      logger.error(" Ha fallado a la hora de crear un destinatario. " + e.getMessage() + " - " + e);
    }
    String mensajeFlash = (entidad.getIdDestinatario() != 0) ? "Destinatario Creado con éxito!"
        : "No se ha podido crear el Destinatario.!";
    flash.addFlashAttribute(SUCCESS, mensajeFlash);

    // Se procede a borrar la sesion.
    status.setComplete();

    return OK;
  }


  private Set<DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad> obtenerListaEntidad(List<Integer> lista, DestinatariosAlertasEntidad usuarioAlerta) {

    Set<DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad> sistemas = new HashSet<DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad>();
    
    for (Integer sistemaId:lista) {
      //Get sistema from DB
      SistemaEntidad sistema = this.tablasServicio.buscarSistemaByIdEntidad(sistemaId);
      
      //Composite key creation
      DestinatarioSistemaKey key = new DestinatarioSistemaKey();
      key.setIdDestinatario(usuarioAlerta.getIdDestinatario());
      key.setIdSistema(sistemaId);
      
      DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad entidad = new DestinatariosAlertasSistemaEntidad();
      entidad.setClave(key);
      entidad.setDestinatario(usuarioAlerta);
      entidad.setSistema(sistema);
      entidad.setActivo(true);
      
      sistemas.add(entidad);
    }
    
    return sistemas;
  }
```

AlertasServicio is an interface for calling RepoClass. What RepoClass does is: *this.persist(destinatarioAlertasEntidad);*

Any help appreciated.

Sorry for the spanish code!

I have tried deleting cascades on SistemaEntidad , but same result.

Comment: I would think that `SistemaEntidad sistema = this.tablasServicio.buscarSistemaByIdEntidad(sistemaId);` causes the problem, as that entity has multiple lazily fetched collections. If lazy fetched, the collection is a proxy only that has not been initialized. You could try to force initialization using `Hibernate.initialize()`

Comment: I have tried with Hibernate.initialize to every lazy collection of SistemaEntidad. Now the error is: `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: es.sjtr.persistencia.TipoSistemaEntidad`...

Comment: To avoid detached entity error, I have changed on SistemaEntidad all cascadeType.All to cascadeType.Merge. Now the problem is Hibernate is trying to insert on table SISTEMAS, but that is wrong because that SISTEMA exists, so PK constrsint violation is throw

Comment: Finally resolved calling to Hibernate.initialize just before persisting DestinatariosAlertasEntidad. Thanks for your help!